# rails 3.1: using plain .html file instead of html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a resume and a profile page that only has html and css.

1. How would you route plain html file in a pre-existing Rails 3.1.0 app?
   I want resume to have whatever.com/resume as the url.
2. Where should I place the html, css, image for this kind of static page?

Thank you.

[edit 1]
I don't want application layout to affect these pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files can be served as is, so long as they are accessible from within the assets or public folders. No fancy routing is required.